# jquery datepicker selecting wrong date on close

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Calendar shows Nov 1866 on open , but after choosing day it sets to current date (year) instead of 1866.

Here is example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/2248/)

```
$('#thedate').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: "-150:-18",
        autoSize: true,
});
```

Comment: It has something to do with the `yearRange`.. if that is taken out.. then the year is correct

Answer (score 2):

The widget doens't appear to be setting the select year until an event is fired within it. The easy way to get around this is to set a defaultDate

```
defaultDate: '01-01-1866'
```

This wont populate the input on page load, but will make sure the values are processed immediately and your selected year is set.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @hairmot for pointing that there is **defaultDate** property, I forgot about it.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/2259/)

Correct code :

```
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: "-150:-18",
        defaultDate: "-150y",
        autoSize: true,
});
```